# How to move an email between folders using RDCOMCLIENT

Tags: r, outlook, rdcomclient

I'd like to automate the movement of emails from one folder (FolderA) to another folder (FolderB) through R using RDCOMCLIENT.

I've written a simple for loop that looks like this:

```
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outlookNameSpace <-  OutApp$GetNameSpace("MAPI")

folderName <-  "FolderA"
destFolder<-"FolderB"


Inbox <- outlookNameSpace$GetDefaultFolder(6) 
FolderA <-  Inbox$folders(folderName) 
FolderB<-Inbox$folders(destFolder)

emails <- FolderA$Items 

i<-1

while(as.numeric(FolderA$Items()$Count())!=0) {
  emails(i)$Move(FolderB)
  i<-i+1

}
```

This code doesn't run smoothly, and I have to rerun it to make sure that all of the emails are moved over. The error message I get everytime the while loop stops is:

```
No support for InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo
Error: Exception occurred.
checkErrorInfo -2147352567
```

Where am I going wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to play with your code and it seems that this error happens whenever the name specified "FolderA" doesn't exist. I wanted to move from Inbox to some other folder and realized that Inbox isn't recognized.
Changing Inbox to some other subfolder actually made your code work.